# Line number not displaying in logcat

Tags: android

Currently my `logcat` is showing function name in which exception has occurred rather than displaying the line number. Attaching the `logcat` for reference. Please help.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
E/AndroidRuntime(23892):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1959)
E/AndroidRuntime(23892):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1984)
E/AndroidRuntime(23892):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:126)
E/AndroidRuntime(23892):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1150)
E/AndroidRuntime(23892):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(23892):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(23892):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4456)
E/AndroidRuntime(23892):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(23892):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(23892):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
E/AndroidRuntime(23892):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
E/AndroidRuntime(23892):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(23892): **Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
E/AndroidRuntime(23892):    at com.healthconverge.docezzy.myappointments.MyAppointments.onCreate(MyAppointments.java)**
E/AndroidRuntime(23892):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
E/AndroidRuntime(23892):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
E/AndroidRuntime(23892):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1923)
```

Comment: Can you try again? Maybe restart emulator, compile again, restart adb?

Comment: You won't get line numbers if the line number information is omitted from the DEX file.  Check your build options to ensure that full debug info is included.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno I tried everything. Restarted pc/emulator but still can't help. Line numbers are appearing for other references except for the main place where problem has caused. At that point it's giving function name.

Comment: @fadden How to set options. Where should I look?

Comment: @fadden Thanks Fadden. Problem solved. Changed build properties.